# How to get the "output" (console screen buffer) Handle for GetConsoleMode() in Windows?

Tags: c, windows, console

I want to do [GetConsoleMode()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolemode) on both input and output because I want to change some flags.

Input is [pretty straightforward](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/reading-input-buffer-events):

```
HANDLE hStdin;
DWORD fdwSaveOldMode;

hStdin = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
GetConsoleMode(hStdin, &fdwSaveOldMode)
```

The output, on the other hand, doesn't seem as easy. One would think that just putting STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE would be enough, but the ["help" pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-screen-buffers) talk about having to make and set your own buffer.

This, and a [page about handles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-handles) mention:

> Specify the CONOUT$ value in a call to CreateFile to open a handle to a console's active screen buffer.

Sounds like a clue, but frankly, I'm unsure what this even means. Can someone show me how to do it properly? Why is output so different than input?

Thank you!

Comment: It means pass `"CONOUT$"` as the filename to `CreateFileA`, or `L"CONOUT$"` as the filename to `CreateFileW`.  The `CreateFile` documentation has an extensive remarks section, including [this information on Consoles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew#consoles)

Comment: However, the examples show that using `STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE` works just fine for opening the console handle: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/clearing-the-screen  This was the very next example after the one you linked in your question; I don't know why you overlooked it.

Comment: @BenVoigt thanks man, you can write an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> One would think that just putting `STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE` would be enough

It is.  The ["Clearing the Screen" example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/clearing-the-screen) has a snippet demonstrating setting console output modes, and it uses `GetStdHandle()`:

> ```
> HANDLE hStdOut;
>
> hStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
>
> // Fetch existing console mode so we correctly add a flag and not turn off others
> DWORD mode = 0;
> if (!GetConsoleMode(hStdOut, &mode))
> {
>     return ::GetLastError();
> }
>
> // Hold original mode to restore on exit to be cooperative with other command-line apps.
> const DWORD originalMode = mode;
> mode |= ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING;
>
> // Try to set the mode.
> if (!SetConsoleMode(hStdOut, mode))
> {
>     return ::GetLastError();
> }
> ```

Some cases where `GetStdHandle` wouldn't work together with console-specific functions would be if the application isn't console-mode (you can get a console in a GUI-mode application by calling `AllocConsole`) or if `stdout` was redirected.

In those cases, you'd need to open a console handle via `CreateFile` and the special filename `"CONOUT$"`.  That will always access a console, if one is associated with your process, even in case `stdout` is not mapped to that console.